# Input Accessory View not Sticking to keyboard when swiping to dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to dismiss the keyboard on swipe down but my input accessory view (custom uiview class) is not sticking to it on swipe down. It leaves a space between it and the keyboard and is not syncing up with it and goes down only after the keyboard disappears. It works fine when activating the keyboard by tapping on the text view/cmd+k to toggle it up and down, but not when swiping it down. From the image I am swiping down to dismiss the keyboard but there is a giant gap. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLV6u.jpg (Sorry if my formatting is bad, I'm still getting used to actually posting on stackoverflow)

Here is my code so far pertaining to it:

// accessory view is anchor to the bottom to start

```
    func layoutInputAccessoryView() {
            view.addSubview(inputFieldAccessoryView)
            inputFieldAccessoryView.anchor(right: view.rightAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor)
            inputFieldAccessoryViewBottomAnchor = inputFieldAccessoryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            inputFieldAccessoryViewBottomAnchor?.isActive = true
        }
```

// swiping to dismiss in collection view
`collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`

// listener for when the keyboard shows/hides

```
    func addKBObserver() {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKBWilShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKBWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        }
```

// method for when the keyboard shows

```
@objc func handleKBWilShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let frame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let rect = frame.cgRectValue
        let height = rect.height
        
        inputFieldContainerBottom?.constant = -height
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

// selector method called when keyboard will hide

```
    @objc func handleKBWillHide(notification: Notification) {
       if let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double {
         UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                    self.inputFieldContainerBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually setting an inputAccessoryView, just a UIView that you're trying to position manually. Whilst that's possible to achieve, using setting the inputAccessoryView property of your UIResponder subclass (e.g. UITextField, UITextView etc)  would give you the positioning for free. This looks like a reasonable example of how to do it using a UIToolbar, but you can also just use a custom UIView: http://findnerd.com/list/view/Add-InputAccessoryView-in-Swift-for-UITextField-and-UITextView/29611/

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! However, this isnt what I am trying achieve. I have everything working fine by manually positioning a custom view class so that it is positioned on top of the keyboard when it shows and at the bottom of the screen when it is hidden. Its just that it doesnt go down with the keyboard, but instead separatey, hence there is the space when trying to swipe to dismiss. I don't know if its an animation issue because I tried to sync it up with the same duration as the keyboard dismiss but it doesn't seem to do anything. Or if its some sort of anchoring issue.